# If the date is less than the sys date, change another column value to null

Tags: sql, sql-server

if date>getdate() then class as null

```
            +----+------------+-------+
            | Id |    Date    | class |
            +----+------------+-------+
            |  1 | 12/31/2022 | A     |
            |  2 | 12/31/2023 | B     |
            |  3 | 5/11/2023  | C     |
            |  4 | 1/15/2020  | D     |
            +----+------------+-------+
```

The result I am expecting

```
            +----+------------+-------+
            | Id |    Date    | class |
            +----+------------+-------+
            |  1 | 12/31/2022 | NUll  |
            |  2 | 12/31/2023 | B     |
            |  3 | 5/11/2023  | C     |
            |  4 | 1/15/2020  | NULL  |
            +----+------------+-------+
```

code not working

```
case when date>getdate() then Class as null else Class end
```

Comment: Is that your actual code? Cos it's got syntax errors which you can easily resolve by reading the documentation.

Comment: Drop the "class as" before null, if that does not work, please add the table definition and a (as-far-as-you-could-tell-should-be-) runnable example. Debugging based on a partial query is error prone to say the least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT 
   CASE 
      WHEN date > GETDATE() 
      THEN NULL
      ELSE Class 
   END AS Class 
FROM table_name;
```

For more information, take a look at the documentation [Use a SELECT statement with a simple CASE expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#a-use-a-select-statement-with-a-simple-case-expression)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can try, from same documentation page that @Youcef LAIDANI pointed you to:

> If this argument is omitted and no comparison operation evaluates to TRUE, CASE returns NULL.

.

```
SELECT 
    Id, 
    [Date], 
    CASE WHEN [Date] <= GETDATE() THEN Class END AS Class 
FROM [YourTable];
```